# Unread comments count in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a Discussion, a Comment and a User. I want to show unread comments count for each User. The question is: where should I place a code, that provides the number of unread comments? This is not a part of Domain, just a presentation concerns.

My idea is to create a UnreadCommentsCounter that depends on UnreadCommentsRepository, accepts DiscussionId and UserId, and returns integer. I will access this UnreadCommentsCounter somewhere in Application layer, in some DiscussionPayloadObject (smart DTO) which has access to Discussion[] and returns what Presentation layer needs.

Questions are:

1. Where should I keep a UnreadCommentsCounter itself? In Application?
   If so, in which folder, Application/Support or Application/Services
   or...?
2. Should I use data provided by UnreadCommentsRepository
   directly inside UnreadCommentsCounter, or add some UnreadComments
   value object and use it inside UnreadCommentsCounter? If I need that
   value object,  where should I keep it? Probably not in Domain. Next
   to UnreadCommentsCounter?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is valid only in the context of an architectural style, so I will give an answer in the case of `CQRS`.

In my projects I use the following structure/layers:

1. Presentation
2. Application
3. **Domain**
4. Infrastructure

The meaning of each of them is very known to the DDD practitioners so there is no point in explaining any but one: the Domain; this layer has 2 sub layers: the Write and the Read.

The `Write` contains the `Aggregates` and the `Value objects` needed by them. It does not contain any dependency to other layers, no repository interface, nothing else but pure, side effects free code.

The `Read` contains the repository, domain services like filtered and optimized lists, counters, all the classes that are used by the `Presentation layer` to display data to the user. This sub-layer does not contain `Presentation` specific technology (like HTML code) The models in here are very thin and very fast. **This is here I would put your `UnreadCommentsCounter` and even the `UnreadCommentsRepository`**. Why here? Because they would contain the logic to calculate the unread comments (domain logic) and that the repo would be very optimized for a particular database (that logic would be implemented using the best available features of a particular vendor). The `UnreadCommentsRepository` would contain data exactly how the Presentation needs in order to keep the layer thin.

Comment: So if you have Domain\Write\DiscussionEntity, where is your DiscussionEntityRepositoryInterface? As I understand, it is in Domain\Read\Discussion\DiscussionEntityRepositoryInterface. But in CQRS the repository for reading and for writing are two different repositories.

Comment: Anyway, if in "my" CQRS I am placing both write and read repositories next to entity in Domain\Model\Discussion\* then I can also place my UnreadComments somewhere there: Domain\Model\Discussion\UnreadComments\*.

Comment: You must split your models (W - R). I don't see any spliting in "your" architecture. Also, `UnreadComments*` is clearly a readmodel.

Comment: @VictorLevandovski You don't need a repository interface for write side. You could have but the domain layer/write side don't need it and don't use it, only application services/command handlers use it.

Comment: Well, but the write side needs some repository to load a model that will be processed and saved, and changes translated to a read side. Where do you place this repository of write models (domain models)?

Comment: @VictorLevandovski the write side of the domain, I repeat, the domain, don't need it, only the write side of the application layer. Please note that aggregates don't load/save persist themselves, never, that's the responsability of a command handler from Application layer.